# How to run R script remotely via Powershell

Tags: r, windows, powershell

We are a Windows shop (desktops and servers) and are hoping to deploy an R project in a way that various scripts can be run from desktop shortcuts by a number of users within our organization.  Ideally we wouldn't have to install R on everyone's PC.

Because I'm assuming `rscript.exe` has a bunch of dependencies that would prevent something as simple as `\\sharename\rscript.exe \\sharename2\script.R` from working, our thinking was that we would need to do this via Powershell.

Is this a viable approach?  Is there a good resource for the specific steps we'd need to do to pull it off?  Is there a better way to solve this?

Comment: Without installing R you probably wont be able to run R scripts. If `rscript.exe` is installed yes it would be as simple as `\\sharename\rscript.exe \\sharename2\script.R`

Comment: Why don't you get your admins to deploy the R runtime to everyone?  It would be wildly inefficient to have everyone run them from a share.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1  Was hoping for ease of long-term administration (at the expense of up-front complexity).  Just giving someone a pre-canned shortcut vs. needing to do an install (for example if someone is on vacation and another person in the department needs to run it just one time).  It seems like there must be a way to install it on a server and run it remotely (I've seen some sites that talk about doing it in linux via ssh, for example).  No?  Also - why would it be inefficient to run from a share (particularly if it's running on the server)?

Comment: Why would anyone need to do an install?  Don't you have sysadmin(s)?

Comment: This is a small, relatively IT-unsophisticated organization.  Installing (and maintaining) software on various uses' PCs for a job that each might run once (or maybe will need again at some undetermined point) doesn't feel like the right answer.  And how would we handle R package management?  Would we have to keep all those individual PCs up to date with whatever changes any future changes to the scripts require?  Again, all for a job an individual user may never run again.

Comment: Just another comment for those who stumble upon this.  Another issue with running locally is that R REALLY doesn't like windows fileshare paths (\\sharename\folder\file).  So if the scripts are to be run locally, you need to have one or more mapped drives to let the scripts get the resources they need (input locations, output locations, etc.).  Which means all those users now have extra mapped drives (which is also likely to encourage them to explore those locations on their own...)

Comment: Why not just create a shiny app?

Comment: That may be the right approach, @RomanLuštrik.  Similar to #2 proposed by not_dave in his answer, I suppose.

Comment: @DovRosenberg I must have missed the answer. I was commenting from the closing queue, I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come across your situation myself. You have couple of options that you can do to solve your problem

1. Set up Rserver and you can execute scripts in Rserver remotely
2. You can convert your scripts to API's and host it in server. Next, create a bash/shell script that can call your API's to do the job.
3. You can host all the scripts and jobs on a server/PC, install ssh. Next create a shell script to shh to PC and run particular script (you can get fancy here).

Comment: Thanks.  Which Rserver were you suggesting?  This one: https://github.com/bgweber/RServer?  It says it's deprecated for windows and hasn't been updated in a couple of years...  Or the Microsoft product now called Machine Learning Server (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/machine-learning-server/install/machine-learning-server-install)?  Or something else?

Comment: use Microsoft one.